# cannot upload photo to my app to webserver

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I create viewcontroller to upload picture from image picker and send it to php webserver but it not upload to server.
This is my code

uploadViewcontroller.m

```
NSData *picdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgShow.image, 90);
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mytestwebsite.com/upload2.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: from-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:picdata]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

and my php code

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "post_comment/original/";      
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadFile = $file;
$randomNumber = rand(0, 99999);
$newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
} else {
    echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}
if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 3000000) {
    exit("Your file is too large.");
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
    $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
    $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was
    $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
    $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    echo "upload finished" ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you miss to fire the mutable request?

Comment: You never submit the request. Use `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession`  to actually submit the request.

Comment: I add `NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
         {
             
             NSData *returnData = data;
             NSLog(@"data recieved!");
             
             //Do what you want with your return data.
             
         }];`    in last line but it don't work

Comment: `[theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];` shouldn't it be `[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];` ?

Comment: Thanks for recheck my code I edited it but it not have respond to upload.

Comment: *Update I Echo php $_FILES['userfile']['name'] but it is blank

Answer (score 0):

check if this works... it worked for me

```
$image = $_POST['userfile'];
$image = str_replace("<","",$image);
$image = str_replace(">","",$image);
$image = str_replace(" ","",$image);
$image = pack("H*", $image);
$filename = "image.png";
$f = fopen($filename,'wb');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);
```